# pdfminer bbox overlapping issue

Tags: reportlab, pdfminer

I got a problem with `pdfminer` when try to draw the text-boxes' coordinates with `reportlab`.

#### Example

The first image is the result which I got from `pdfminer`.
[image]

What I noticed:
When the line margin is not the same for one paragraph (see the hanging indent in PDF's rendered text below), then it is overlapping when I try to draw the rectangle with `reportlab`.

[image]

I tried to solve this issue by fixing the line margin, but then got a worse result with other parts.

#### Code

```
laparams = LAParams(line_margin = 1.0, detect_vertical = True)
```

Comment: Please provide more code as [example]. A link to the PDF would also help to reproduce. What are you trying to do - extract the citation/bibliographic reference 13 as text? What is your desired output? Please ask a question.